# Can I set the date parameter format to date instead of Date/Time?

Tags: reporting-services

I am designing a report in SSRS. I'm making the user choose a start and end date(@Sdate & @Edate) That's why I set the dates as parameters. The dates show the day of the end of the month and the last 12 months are available.

I'm fetching the @Sdate and @Edate parameters from a different query by saying "Get Values ​​from a query". The result returned from my query is as follows;

| StartDate |
| --- |
| 2021-12-31 |
| 2022-01-31 |
| 2022-11-30 |

When I want to select the dates to run the report, the dates appear as Date/Time format.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpWnb.png)

But in the query I got, it only showed up as date... What could be causing the problem? Also, I cannot set the type of the @Sdate or @Edate parameters to "Date". It just gives me "Date/Time" option. Could the problem come from here?

Thank you all!

I tried converting the dates to text format, but it didn't work. I also used the FORMAT(Date, 'dd-MM-yyyy') function but got no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different fields for the parameter value and label so if your dataset query that gets your dates has a preformatted date column, just use that as the label.

For example

```
SELECT TheDate, DateLabel = Format(TheDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy') 
FROM myDateTable
```

would give you something like this

[image]

Then in the parameter setup, use the `TheDate` field as the parameter value (as this is a date type) and the `DateLabel` field as the parameter label.

Be aware that you might still have to cast the parameter value to a date in your main dataset query if the data you are ultimately querying has times..

e.g.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE CAST(myDateColumm as DATE) = CAST(@myDateParameter as DATE)
```

Comment: Hi,

The method you described worked. Thank you so much for your support :)